# Admin log in using mysqli and php

Tags: php, html, mysqli, authentication

I've tried to create a member login for my page. I can get it to work for normal users but when i enter the admin login details it doesn't log in at all.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="root"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="SafeTNetD"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
  $pword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['pword']);
  $memberType = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['memberType']);
} 

$sel_user = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$pword' AND memberType = '$memberType'";

$run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sel_user);

$check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);

if($check_user > 0){
  if($memberType == 1) {
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    echo "<script> location.replace('admin.php'); </script>";
  }
  elseif ($memberType == 0) {
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    echo "<script> location.replace('home.php'); </script>";
  } 
} else {
   echo "<script>alert('Email or password is not correct, try again!')</script>";

}


</body>
</html>
```

When logging in with a normal user email and password it redirects me to the home page but using the admin login details it alerts me that either the email or password is incorrect, however i know the email and password are right.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Double check the value of `$_POST['memberType']` ?

Comment: echo your query and check what it return!!

Comment: what us the value of $_POST['memberType'] ?

Answer (score 0):

Here mysqli_num_rows is not returning a positive count. It's not a problem with username or password. It could be something wrong in your query.

Since you said it works for normal user, check if the $_POST['memberType'] matches the value you have in db.

Comment: @ASR what's wrong with it? it goes to the else condition because mysqli_num_rows  is not returning a positive number?

Comment: Ahh I thought its your statement that 'mysqli_num_rows does not return a positive count.' Now its much clear on your comment what you are about to say :)